# Best method to train Tesseract 3.02

Tags: ocr, tesseract

i'm wondering what is the best method to train Tesseract (kind of text/TIFF and so on) for a particular kind of documents, with these particularities:

- the structure and main text of the documents is always the same
- the only things that change are 5 alphanumeric codes (THIS ARE THE REAL IMPORTANT THING TO DETECT!)
- Some of thes codes are bold

At the moment I used standard trained datas, I detect the entire text and I extrapolate the codes with some regular expressions.
It's okay, but I've got errors sometimes, for example:

0 / O

L / I / 1

Please someone knowns some "tricks" to improve precision?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

during training part of Tesseract, you have to make a file manually to give to the engine in order to specify ambiguous characters.

For more information look at the "unicharambigs" part of the [Tesseract documentation](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3).

Best Regards.